# angular.js:13236 TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, datagrid

I'm using dxDataGrid UI widget of DevExtreme product in my angular project. When i want to use dxDataGrid ui widget in any ex-dialog, i see an error in the  browser. Actually dxDataGrid is working fine but i wonder why am i seeing an error in the browser?[image]

My ex-dialog code:

```js
public topluFaturaIcerikListGridContainer;
        public topluIcerikList = [];
        TopluFaturaIcerik() {
            var ctrl = this;
            var TopluFaturaIcerikDialog = ctrl.exDialog.openPrime({
                animation: false,
                width: 'auto',
                minWidth: '50%',
                scope: ctrl.$scope,
                cacheTemplate: false,
                template: '..',
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                controller: function ($scope) {                 
                    ctrl.topluFaturaIcerikListGridContainer = {
                        selection: { mode: 'single' /* 'multiple'*/ },
                        allowColumnReordering: true,
                        allowColumnResizing: true,
                        columnAutoWidth: true,
                        filterRow: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        bindingOptions: {
                            dataSource: 'topluIcerikList'
                        },
                        paging: { pageSize: 5 },
                        pager: {
                            showPageSizeSelector: true,
                            allowedPageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
                            showInfo: true,
                            infoText: 'Sayfa:{0}/{1} (Toplam: {2} kayıt)'
                        },
                        columnWidth: 'auto',
                        columns: [
                            { dataField: "DT_FATURA_KESIM_TARIHI", visible: true, caption: "Fatura Tarihi", dataType: 'date', format: 'dd.MM.yyyy' },
                            { dataField: "CH_FATURA_SERI", visible: true, caption: "Fatura Seri" },
                            { dataField: "CH_FATURA_NO", visible: true, caption: "Fatura No" },
                            { dataField: "FATURA_TIPI", visible: true, caption: "Fatura Türü" },
                            { dataField: "CH_IRSALIYE_NO", visible: true, caption: "İrsaliye No" }
                        ]
                    };

                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post a working code in jsfiddle or code pen

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? You can use a debug version of devextreme, next refer this article - [Automatically pause on any exception](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception) then you will be able to walk through a callstack and analyze your code.